# CNAME redirecting of godaddy domain to AWS s3 changes the url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hosting, web-hosting

Basically I have two buckets hosting my static website.

Bucket `www.website.com` redirects to bucket `website.com` that contains my website.

**I can access the website perfectly using the aws endpoint and when i access `website.com` the aws endpoint also works**

However, after accessing `website.com` and after the website loads, the url changes to the endpoint. Instead of the url bar showing `website.com` the url changes to the whole endpoint for reasons I still can't figure out.

Can someone help me on this please?
Thank you so much